# How to access a specific item on the most similar row with euclidean distance?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a list `L` of arrays:

```
L = ( array1,
      array2,
      array3,
      array4... )
```

This list is created starting from a Pandas data frame, thus, every single row of the old data frame is now an array inside a list.

Using Euclidean Distance I want to:

1. Iterate through all the arrays
2. Select only arrays in which the **2nd item** is included between `10` and `100`
3. Given an array `arr1`, select the most similar one (let's say `arr4`)
4. Replace the **2nd** item in `arr4` with **2nd** item in `arr1`

To visualize it:

1. Iterate through all the arrays

   ```
    L = ([87, 30,  45,  99],
        [11,  21,  31,  41],
        [560, 47,  85,  328],
        [167, 32,  98,  379] )
   ```
2. Select only arrays in which the 2nd item is included between `10` and `100`

   ```
   L = ([87,  30,  45,  99],
        [11,  21,  31,  41],
        [560, 47,  85,  328],
        [85,  33,  43,  97] )
   ```
3. Given an array `arr1`, select the most similar one (let's say `arr4`)

   ```
   array 1 = ( [87, 30,  45,  99] )

   array 4 = ( [85, 32,  43,  97] )
   ```

   Now let's call for simplicity:

   **P**  =  30 (array 1, 2nd element)

   **X**  =  32 (array 4, 2nd element)
4. Replace the **2nd** item in `arr4`(P) inside `arr1` 2nd position (X)

   ```
   array 1 = ([87, 32, 45, 99])
   ```

Many thank and advance for whatever hint that can be useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np

L = np.array([
  [87, 30,  45,  99],
  [11,  21,  31,  41],
  [560, 47,  85,  328],
  [167, 32,  98,  379]
])
```

For point 2 you can use `np.where` which return an array of condition.nonzero() that indicates where *condition* is **True**. Then you can put this array as index.

```py
result = L[np.where((L[:,1]>10)&(L[:,1]<100))]
```

To given array e.g `arr1`, we can use following method (I don't know if it's best, but it works).

```py
L2 = np.array([
  [87,  30,  45,  99],
  [11,  21,  31,  41],
  [560, 47,  85,  328],
  [85,  33,  43,  97]
])

def dist(a):
  return np.linalg.norm(L2[0]-a)

distances = np.apply_along_axis(dist, 1, L2)
index = np.ma.MaskedArray(result, result==0).argmin() #remove first element which dist is min (0)
print(L2[index])
```